# Strong vs weak - How to define a property that may or may not be connected to a IBOutlet?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, xib

I'm writing a reusable class that has a UITableView property as an IBOutlet. However, I want the class to create a UITableView if it's not connected to a xib and therefore nil. If I set it to weak, then allocating the UITableView programmatically doesn't seem to work. However, if I make it strong, then if a xib is used, it's won't necessarily deallocate correctly. What's the best way to handle this case?

Comment: The table view property can be weak as long as you add the table view to some parent view in the same block where the table view is allocated.

Comment: Why it is not deallocated correctly! when the view controller gets deallocated your custom class will also deallocated. therefore, the strong property also will be deallocated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Properties are usually declared weak when the author understands that someone else retains the object.  A good example of this is a view controller that wants to keep pointers to subviews of its main view.  The main view's subview collection is an array, and the array retains its elements (and so on for sub-sub-views).

So it's correct for your table view to be declared weak, notwithstanding whether it is setup via an IBOutlet.  But initializing a weak pointer takes a little gymnastics so that you can first establish a retained relation to the object, before making an assignment to the weak property.

To demonstrate:

```
// assumes
@property(weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (!self.tableView) {  // if the outlet was not setup in IB
        // declare a stack variable that will be retained within the scope of this condition
        UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] init];
        // do whatever is needed to configure the tableView pointed to by this stack variable

        // this is key, make it a subview (establishing a retained relationship with subviews) first
        [self.view addSubview:tableView];
        // now we can assign it to our weak property
        self.tableView = tableView;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is perfect. Creating the UITableView *tableView =.... first and setting it as the weak property fixed it.